# Check if Linux Kernel is real time or not from kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, real-time, kernel-module

We have a kernel module which is used on both real time (RT) and non-real time Linux kernel. Module uses the function get_user_pages_remote. However, there is a version check since the module needs to work for older kernels:

```
#if(LINUX_VERSION_CODE > KERNEL_VERSION(4,4,41))
   res = get_user_pages_remote(...);
#else
   res = get_user_pages(...);
#endif
```

I'm trying to build this module for kernel 4.4.88-18-rt, but it does not have get_user_pages_remote(...) API. Any suggestion on how to handle this?

1. Should I check for rt version and use get_user_pages ?
2. Is there a wrapper API common to all kernels which will internally call correct API?

Thanks

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/ Might give you more feedback.

Comment: You want to check if rt patches are installed ?

Comment: And get_user_pages_remote was added after 4.4

Comment: During compile time, I need to tell compiler to chose get_user_pages if *_remote is not available. How do I do that?